# Use findIndex, but start looking in a specific position

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following extract of code:

```
private getNextFakeLinePosition(startPosition: number): number{
        return this.models.findIndex(m => m.fakeObject);
}
```

This function returns me the index of the first element which has the property `fakeObject` with the true value.

What I want is something like this, but instead of looking for the all items of the array, I want to start in a specific position (`startPosition`).

Note: This is typescript but the solution could be in javascript vanilla.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with `slice`:

```
private getNextFakeLinePosition(startPosition: number): number {
  const index = this.models.slice(startPosition).findIndex(m => m.fakeObject);
  return index === -1 ? -1 : index + startPosition;
}
```

It'll slice your input array and find the index on a subarray. Then - at the end, just add the `startPosition` to get the real index.

Answer (score 12):

The callback to `findIndex()` receives the current index, so you could just add a condition that way:

```
private getNextFakeLinePosition(startPosition: number): number {
    return this.models.findIndex((m, i) => i >= startPosition && m.fakeObject);
}
```

Not the most efficient solution, but should be OK as long as your array is not too large.

Answer (score 5):

In this case i would probably use **for** loop. It doesn't add overhead to slice array and avoids unnecessary indices check.

```js
const findStartFromPos = <T>(predicate: (e: T) => boolean, array: T[], startFrom: number): number => {
  for (let i = startFrom; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(array[i])) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A vague, but working solution would be to skip the indices until we reach the start index:

```
let startIndex = 4;
array.findIndex((item, index) => index >= startIndex && item.fakeObject);
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant method.  Just skipping until the n index is reached.